# Does database affect classes?

Tags: database, class, design-patterns, dao

I had created one class User and UserDAOImpl class for querying DB using class User. As there is one table to be queried, these two classes are sufficient for me.

[image]
What if there is a case where new fields are to be added to that one table is to be divided into 3 tables( user_info, user_profile and user_address) to store user?

As new fields are added, I need to change classes User and UserDAOImpl, it seems these two are not sufficient. It seems database changes affect my classes.

In this case, do I need to divide class User into 3 classes as tables are changes?
Can any one suggest me how can I solve this without making too many changes?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  I don't see a reason why you'd have to change the `User` class if the underlying data model changes.  You'd have to change the DAL class which maps the two, of course.  And, if you need to add a new property to the `User` class then naturally you'd have to, well, add it.  But inherently I'm not seeing any tight coupling here.

Comment: Thanks. I can add new properties to the existing class User and make some changes to it's DAO. In future if it is required to go with ORM, can I use the same class User to update data into 3 tables?

Comment: If the ORM supports that mapping, sure.  If it doesn't, then no.  Any choice of framework is going to limit you to what that framework supports.  If that happens then perhaps a custom layer can be added between the business objects and the ORM for a custom mapping.  It depends on what's more valuable to the system... business models which match the business logic or data structures which match the persistence logic.  There is no one right answer.

Comment: @satyanarayana: depending on the association between the tables, it's possible, but usually a bad idea. Why would you introduce 3 different tables in the database if you treat them as a single one in the application? If there's no good reason to have 3 tables, then use a single one. And if there's a good reason to have 3 tables, then you probably want to not hide this reality in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your table splits will be one to one with `user_info`--`user_profile` and `user_address`_`user_profile` (assuming that user_profile is a main table), you can simply handle that change in your DAO class.
If you will spits that table with foreign keys binding tables primary keys(relation one to one). then you will just have to adjust your queries in your dao from

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM users_profile up
   JOIN user_info ui ON up.id=ui.id
   JOIN user_address ua ON up.id=ua.id
WHERE up.id=1
```

(of course instead of star you should point fields desired and probably use aliases for easier access to them in DAO class)

then put values to a class accordingly.

However i would consider to change your class model to fit your database. Especially, when rows in `user_address` can be pointed by more than one user. in this case i would create class `Address` and used it in `User` class. This way your program is much easier to understand and easier to develop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it require to maintain an attribute userID in both classes User and Address or add Address as an attribute in class User or inherit Address from User? which is the best solution?

Comment: Can't say that i'm experts, so i don't wanna misguide you. But if i ware you, i would do a User and Address (both, classes and tables) without that user_profile. I think that user_info and uer_profile should be as one. In class you use Addres as a field, and in table user you should do a id_address field that is foreign key to table user_address. This way you can have relation many users to a one address. This approach is more objective and easy to understand.

Comment: But keep in mind, that binding many user to one address can cause situation, when one of user binned to address, changes it. If you will update address that he is binned to, you also changes data of other users, which is not necessarily right. In this situation you can input new address, if it has more than one user etc.